# Assigning an integer to a character variable

Tags: c++, scope

I was trying to assign an integer to a `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char` variables, to understand the results of the same. I am running this code on a 64 bit Mac OS. I am baffled with the response and am looking for someone to help me out with the same. I am not looking  at the sizeof result, I am only trying to understand why printing the value of variables result in weird characters.

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main() {
     char a = 2;
     unsigned char b = 10;
     signed char c = 200;
     cout<<"Regular char variable value "<<a<<"\t"<<"size of the variable is "<<sizeof(a)<<"\n";
     cout<<"Regular char variable value "<<b<<"\t"<<"size of the variable is "<<sizeof(b)<<"\n";
     cout<<"Regular char variable value "<<c<<"\t"<<"size of the variable is "<<sizeof(c)<<"\n";

 }
```

And the output of this code is following:

```
Regular char variable value     size of the variable is 1
Regular char variable value 
                size of the variable is 1
Regular char variable value ?   size of the variable is 1
```

Please note that the 2nd line in the output is garbled, which adds to the complexity of the output.

Comment: Its not the size of I am concerned about, its the values of the variables that I am worried about, I am sorry I should have been clearer, size of was printed just as an extra piece of information.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `cout<<a` tries to print `a` as a character instead of a number (the same for `b` and `c`).

Looking at an ASCII table
[image: ASCII table]

tells you that character 2 is `STX`, 10 is `LINEFEED`, and `200` is up in the non-standard special characters section, or would be. Note that you assign 200 to a `signed char` whose maximum value is 127, so you'll actually end up with a negative number.

Since none of these characters have visible representations on the terminal, you'll see blanks.

To print them in numerical fashion you should use, e.g.

```
cout<<(int)a;
```